# How do I copy and paste and preserve the original form?

Tags: discussion

First of all, it would be helpful if I knew a way to copy and paste that would preserve the sigma notation or traditional form of what I copy. I hear about latex, but there is no "copy as latex" option. I tried recopying from the browser back into mathematica and I got a non-functional version. I notice everyone else pastes into the nice blue boxes, how do I do that as well? this is an example below

In[63]:= N[!( *UnderoverscriptBox[([Sum]), (n = 1), ((+1) Floor[ *RadicalBox[(49), (2)]])](((((10^((n*2)))) + 1))/((((10^((((((n^2))))*2)))) ((((10^((n*2)))) - 1)))))), (49)*2]

That is what I copy into the browser, and when I recopy from the browser into mathematica I get a non-functional because the little multiply symbols in front of UnderoverscripBox and RadicalBox are highlighted as non-functional. What gives? I'm going crazy because I can't paste and preserve the original form. Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/74064/3066). Below is the image of a section of the notebook I used to get one of your posted code expressions into useable form.

[image: notebook]

It is pasted into our code editor indenting with at least four spaces, like so

```
 N[
   Sum[Floor[(2*10^((49 - 10) - Mod[-(10 - n^2), n]*2))/((10^n - 1)*2)], 
     {n, 1, Floor[(49 - 10)^(1/2)]}], 
  50]
```

Comment: N[Sum[(10^(n*2) + 1)/(10^(n^2*2)*
          (10^(n*2) - 1)), 
     {n, 1, (Plus[1])*Floor[49^(1/2)]}], 
   49*2]
str = StringDrop[ToString@%, 2]
Last /@ StringPosition[str, "02"]/2                                                       That is the best I can do by selecting Covert To>Input Form, but why can't I get the form to hold better. And about this SE Editor, how or where do I open that program?

Comment: @user24719. The SE editor is where you entered your question. `N[Sum[(10^(n*2) + 1)/(10^(n^2*2)* (10^(n*2) - 1)), {n, 1, (Plus[1])*Floor[49^(1/2)]}], 49*2]` is what you should copy and paste into the SE editor.

Comment: It don't get any better than that? That is unreadable to me, and I know what it is supposed to be, so I would't expect anyone else to know what they are looking at either. I see at the beginning of your post that you did indeed somehow get it to copy and paste correctly. So do I have to put HoldForm in front before I convert to and copy or do I use FullForm[HoldForm[expr]]? Sorry if I'm not following, please help me improve the quality of my questions. And I am already banned from answering and asking questions, so all that's left for me is the comment section as far as establishing dialogue

Comment: Plain text forms such as `N[Sum[(10^(n*2) + 1)/(10^(n^2*2)* (10^(n*2) - 1)), {n, 1, (Plus[1])*Floor[49^(1/2)]}], 49*2]` is the gold standard for posting here. Such forms have the advantage of easy transferability between _Mathematica_ here and back again. In _Mathematica_ plain text input can be converted back to StandardFrom you think that is prettier of more readable.

Comment: I understand now, thanks